# Как заменить символ _ на пробел/заставить программу распознавать пробел как символ. Си

Tags: c

Я написал программу "Заметки". В ее обязанности входит: распознать текст введенный юзером и создать файл с заметками.

Суть проблемы в том, что программа записывает в файл текст только до пробела.
Здесь я вижу только два выхода: заставлять пользователя писать слова через _, а
потом менять его на пробел, или же заставить программу считывать пробел тоже.

```
FILE* file = fopen(n, "w");
printf("Напишите здесь нужную вам заметку:\n");
scanf("%s", &b);
printf("%s - введённая заметка\n", b);
fprintf(file, "%s", n);
fprintf(file, "%s", ":");
fprintf(file, "%s", b);
dd();
printf("Заметки созданны.\n");
printf("Они лежат в одной папке с программой\n");
fclose(file);
void exit (int code);
```

Comment: Кто мешает считывать ввод пользователя полностью? Как вы это делаете сейчас?

Comment: Компьютер по умолчанию не хочет распознавать пробел как символ.

Comment: @Timafiva покажите пример кода, где идёт считывание.

Comment: *"Компьютер по умолчанию не хочет распознавать пробел как символ"* - ну не пишите глупости! Приведите код, покажем, как надо. Кстати, поздравляю - вы первый, кто пишет, что виноват компьютер. Обычно все начинают кричать об ошибках в компиляторе... :)

Comment: FILE* file = fopen(n, "w");  
    printf("Напишите здесь нужную вам заметку:\n");  
    scanf("%s", &b);  
    printf("%s - введённая заметка\n", b);  
    fprintf(file, "%s", n);                    
    fprintf(file, "%s", ":");  
    fprintf(file, "%s", b);  
    dd();  
    printf("Заметки созданны.\n");     
    printf("Они лежат в одной папке с программой\n");     
    fclose(file);     
    void exit (int code);

Comment: @Harry да, я такой)

Comment: Ну конечно, сначала просить считать слово - `scanf("%s", &b);` - а потом возмущаться, что считано слово... Читайте про `fgets()`. Кстати, смущает заодно наличие `&` перед переменной. У вас `b` как объявлено?

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое! b - как char

Comment: ОДИН??????!!!!!! Не массив?

Comment: Как char b[1000];

Comment: Я хотел ограничить количество введённых символов юзером.

Comment: А, ну тогда другое дело. Но при этом, кстати, `&` все равно не обязателен, потому что `b` все равно преобразуется в указатель...

Comment: Ну, ограничьте. `fgets()` как раз позволяет считывать столько, сколько хотите. А помешать пользователю ввести больше - это надо уже принимать совсем крутые меры :)

Comment: ))) Спасибо огромное за помощь! Нигде не смог найти. Только вы подсказали

Comment: Ну что, я закрываю этот вопрос как отвеченный)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вместо scanf() используйте gets() (или fgets) и будет вам счастье. Так будет читать всю строку со всеми пробелами до символа перевода строки (конца строки) или конца файла.

Comment: *gets()* ни в коем случае не используйте.

Comment: Нет уже никакого `gets`. Исключен из стандарта С в 2011 году.

Comment: Ну автор ответа пишет же про *fgets()* - какие проблемы?!

Answer (score -2):

Как насчет того,чтоб попробовать сверять символ с аски кодом пробела и если они равны,подсавлять вместо него код пробела?

Comment: А с самим пробелом сравнивать недостаточно профессионально выглядит?

Comment: Ну я говорю то,что сам когда-то делал